# AutoPostBack not working in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autopostback

I have  several form elements that are hidden when the page is loaded. The user can un-hide the form elements when they select a radio button. There are two columns to the form. One for the user and one for the user's spouse. The default is to **hide** the spouse boxes when the page is initially loaded.

1. The users boxes communicate fine to the code-behind.
2. If the spouse boxes are shown they do not communicate to the code
   behind.
3. If the page is navigated away from and returned to (like a save and
   go back) if the spouse boxes were un-hidden, they DO communicate
   back to the code-behind.
4. ***On my localhost the text-boxes communicate with the code-behind file
   after being un-hidden, the desired action, but deployed to the production server they
   do not.***

**ASP**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scmMgr1" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" 
AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled" 
CompositeScript-ScriptMode="Release" 
EnableCdn="true" 
EnableCdnFallback="true" 
EnableScriptLocalization="true"></asp:ScriptManager> 

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCurrentAgeUser" OnTextChanged="txtCurrentAgeUser_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Columns="2" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCurrentAgeSpouse" OnTextChanged="txtCurrentAgeSpouse_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Columns="2" />
```

**CODE-BEHIND**

```
protected void HideSpouseFields () {
  txtCurrentAgeSpouse.Visible = false;
}

protected void ShowSpouseFields () {
  txtCurrentAgeSpouse.Visible = false;
}

protected void txtCurrentAgeUser_OnTextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (txtRetirementAgeUser.Text.Trim ().Length > 0) {
       txtLifeExpectancyUser.Text = LifeExpectancy (Convert.ToInt16 (txtRetirementAgeUser.Text.Trim ()), rdoGenderUser.SelectedValue).ToString ();
  }
}

protected void txtCurrentAgeSpouse_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (txtRetirementAgeSpouse.Text.Trim ().Length > 0) {
      txtLifeExpectancySpouse.Text = LifeExpectancy (Convert.ToInt16 (txtRetirementAgeSpouse.Text.Trim ()), rdoGenderSpouse.SelectedValue).ToString ();
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get any client side JavaScript errors when you check the console in the browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

You are using UpdatePanel? Try using it to test.